# How to display data on recycleView corresponding to users?

Tags: kotlin

I don't know how to display the respective user's data on recycleView

users
2rNmSmeHq3eKryK2XeAfkxl555G3
user
-NZ05JXZ0d0p8N6e2AE7
-NZ05KvTaIa0qWHoi6ax
XvaRvv68GPNYhOVPJiCULfsMOMm2
user
-NZ05Q8B-KAOWlK07-LJ

```
private fun getDataFromFirebase() {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user")
        .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (userSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val user = userSnapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)
                    if (user?.userId == auth.currentUser?.uid) {
                        ds.add(user!!)
                    }
                }
                userAdapter = UserAdapter(ds)
                binding.rc.adapter = userAdapter
                // Hiển thị danh sách các công thức
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
}
```